# Differential Equations.Is it possible to solve?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$ e^y(1+x^2)dy-2x(1+e^y)dx =0 $$
$$ e^y(1+x^2)dy=2x(1+e^y)dx $$

multiplies both sides by $$ \frac{1}{(1+x^2)(1+e^y)} $$
$$ $$
$$\frac{e^y dy}{1+e^y}=\frac{2xdx}{1+x^2} $$

introduced under the integral sign

$$\int\frac{e^y dy}{1+e^y}=\int\frac{2xdx}{1+x^2} $$

After the conversion was

$$Ln|1+e^y|=Ln|1+x^2|+C $$
$$ 1+e^y=(1+x^2)*C $$
$$ e^y= (1+x^2)*C-1$$
$$$$
And here is the ***main question***, if I can make both sides of the logarithm to express Y

$$ ln (e^y)=Ln ((1+x^2)*C-1)$$
$$ y*Ln(e)=Ln ((1+x^2)*C-1) $$
$$ y=Ln ((1+x^2)*C-1)$$

**Can I do that?**

Comment: This looks very correct to me !

Comment: Absolutely (and this has nothing to do with the differential equation), since the function $\ln$ is monotonous. Take care that you can take the logarithm of positive arguments only, but this is ensured here, as $e^y>0$.

Comment: $f(x)=f(y)\implies x=y$ requires $f$ to be monotonous (or at least one-one).

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: $$e^y > 0 $$ e will always be strictly greater than zero

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that just make sure that $Ln(1+x^2)*C>1$ since the domain of logarithm function are the set of positive real numbers.